# What is wrong with this Regular Expression?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am trying to create a test to verify that a link is rendered on a webpage.

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong on this assertion test:

```
self.assertRegexpMatches( response.content, r'<a href="/questions/?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a>')
```

I know that the markup is on the page because I copied it from response.content

I tried to use the regular expression in the Python shell:

```
In [27]: links = """<div class="tabsA"><a href="/questions/?sort=active" title="Most recently updated questions">active</a><a href="/questions/?sort=newest" title="most recently asked questions">newest</a><a href="/questions/?sort=hottest" title="most active questions in the last 24 hours">hottest</a><a href="/questions/?sort=mostvoted" title="most voted questions">most voted</a><a href="/questions/?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a></div>"""

In [28]: re.search(r'<a href="/questions/?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a>', links)
```

For some reason it's not working their either.

How do I create the regular expression so it works?

Comment: you have to escape the questionmark. so its re.search(r'somestuff\?somemorestuff')

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek response: What's wrong with it is that you're trying to use a regex to parse markup.  ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Why are you using a regex here? There's absolutely no reason to. You're just matching a simple string. Use:

```
self.assertContains(response, '<a href="/questions/?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a>')
```

Answer (score 4):

The `?` in your regex is getting interpreted as a [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (end of this part):

`<a href="/questions/?...`

Thus the engine never matches the literal `?` that appears in the string, and instead matches an optional `/` at that position. Escape it with a backslash like so:

`<a href="/questions/\?...`

Answer (score 1):

You should escape "`?`", because that symbol has a special meaning on regex.

```
>>> re.search(r'<a href="/questions/\?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a>', links)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ? character is a special RegEx Character and must be escaped.

The follow regexp would work

```
<a href="/questions/\?sort=elite" class="on" title="Staff Selected Questions">elite</a>
```

Note the \ before the ?

A great tool for messing around with RegEx can be found here:

http://regexpal.com/

It can save you an awful lot of time and headaches...

Comment: Personally, I prefer expresso

Answer (score -1):

It's probably the "<" and ">" characters. In some regular expression syntaxes they are special characters that indicate beginning and end of line.

You might look at a [regular expression tester](http://alexandershapovalov.com/regular-expressions-tester-regex-master-74/) tool to help you learn them.

Comment: `<` and `>` have no special meaning in Python excepting if they are used in a named capturing group `(?P<name>...)` (or, additionally, the `<` is used in the lookbehind syntaxes `(?<...)` and `(?<!...)`).